# How to %JAVA_HOME% environment variable in MinGw shell

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, mingw

I installed MinGw on Windows 10, and followed some online instructions to create a JNI project. Although, I followed the instructions verbatim, gcc can not find the jni.h file. This file however is in the /include directory of my JAVA_HOME. Here are the commands I issued:

```
sansari@DESKTOP/c/Users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

sansari@DESKTOP/c/Users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ echo %JAVA_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME%

sansari@DESKTOP/c/Users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ gcc -Wl, --add-stdcall-alias -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '--add-stdcall-alias'

sansari@DESKTOP/c/Users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c
HelloJNI.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.

sansari@DESKTOP/c/Users/sansari/Documents/source/java
```

I am trying to make sure I know the file structure that needs to be in place for a JNI project, and also dig in a bit more on how to exchange different structures from JAVA classes to the native code and vise versa.

I also tried it this way:

```
$ gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"\include" -I"\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c
HelloJNI.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminate.
```

@Chrono Kitsune- Thanks; Here is the result:

```
sansari@DESKTOP-/c/Users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"

sansari@DESKTOP-/c/Users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"\include" -I"\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c
HelloJNI.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

The strange thing is that I set the path to java directory also and reboot the machine. When I issue java, the shell finds the executable.

[image: Environment Variables] I added JAVA_HOME to my variables, and to my path variable. I still get the same message. I also rebooted the machine.

```
sansari@DESKTOP-/c/users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"\include" -I"\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c
HelloJNI.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.

sansari@DESKTOP-/c/users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c
HelloJNI.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

It worked!

```
sansari@DESKTOP-/c/users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"$JAVA_HOME\include" -I"$JAVA_HOME\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HelloJNI.c

sansari@DESKTOP-/c/users/sansari/Documents/source/java
$ ls
HelloJNI.c  HelloJNI.class  HelloJNI.h  HelloJNI.java  hello.dll
```

Comment: This sounds more like a topic for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: The MinGW shell uses a different syntax for variables. For example `echo %PATH%` doesn't work as intended. However, `echo $PATH` does. You'd need to use the POSIX shell syntax `export VAR="value"` instead of the Windows/DOS syntax `set VAR="value"`.

Comment: @Turing85- I would be glad to move it, but this is a question about compiler configuration and how to build a java project. I feel it is legit. What programmer has not run into the issue of files not being visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MinGW shell uses a different syntax for variables -- the syntax specified for a POSIX shell. For example `echo %PATH%` doesn't work as it does in a Windows/DOS command shell. However, `echo $PATH` does.

You'd need to use the POSIX shell syntax `export VAR="value"` instead of the Windows/DOS syntax `set VAR="value"`.

An alternative to avoid this step in future sessions is to [add a new Windows user environment variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726962.aspx):

1. Type <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Type **`control sysdm.cpl,3`** to open "Advanced system settings".
3. Click the **`Environment Variables`** button.
4. Click the **`New`** button in the top section (it is labeled "User variables for <username>" in English releases.)
5. Add your `JAVA_HOME` variable and its value.
6. Click OK on all of the dialog boxes to save the changes.
7. Open a new MinGW shell and test using `echo $JAVA_HOME`.
8. You might need to close all MinGW shells or even log out and log in to effect the changes.

Comment: Same problem had to globally expose a variable in GIT-windows msys console so that all cmd line tools see it `export GOLANG=/c/projects/golang-repo/` did the trick.

Comment: I can echo JAVA_HOME, no problem, but It does not understand the java command.